# Sqlite java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, sqlite, runtime-error

I have a program that uses Sqlite database. It works fine on Windows (exported jar or directly in Eclipse) but when I move it to linux server (plan is to use run it at certain intervals, cron job). I'm exporting it to jar from Eclipse and packing the sqlite-jdbc4-3.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar with it. Error is this:

```
/$ /usr/bin/java -jar /home/username/Software.jar /home/username/
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/sqlite-3.8.2-amd64-libsqlitejdbc.so: /tmp/sqlite-3.8.2-amd64-libsqlitejdbc.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:161)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:145)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:66)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:21)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:44)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:113)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    ....
```

So before you ask, I've made sure that sqlite-3.8.2-amd64-libsqlitejdbc.so in /tmp/ has all permissions (rwxrwxrwx). Still that native library is causing problems. It does get copied in /tmp/ folder though. That being said I totally suck in Linux... and for that reason I'm pretty much clueless what to try next.

What should I do? Switch connector?

EDIT:
Solved the problem by using System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/home/username/"); Apparently it for some reason couldn't execute the native library from tmp folder... Probably because it was created by root. Also I had to revert back to sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar because the new one crashes on linux.

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911385/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-sqlite-core-nativedb-open. Your solution did not make any difference in my case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and I found the solution in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro/issues/180):

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/some/other/tmpdir bin/cerebro
```

Also look at [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911385).